# TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

Tags: python-2.7

I want to use print format to print strings and numbers, and I 
have the following code:

```
John = {'strength': 10, 'skill': 10}
character1 = "John"
strength = eval(character1)['strength']
skill = eval(character1)['skill']
print " %d " % eval(character1)['strength']
print " %d " % strength
print "$s's strength is: %d, and $s's skill is: %d" % (character1, strength, character1, skill)
print "$s's strength is: %d, and $s's skill is: %d" % character1, eval(character1)['strength'], character1, eval(character1)['skill']
```

The first two print I have no error, they print 10, the the last two print give me:
"TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str".

I do not understand why, please give some pointers, thanks!

Comment: Did you try printing `type(skill)`?

Comment: Yes, it is type int. and I have no problem printing it by itself, as showed in the first two print statements.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the mistake: `$s` should be `%s`.