# TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not unicode

Tags: python, html, typeerror, traceback

I am getting a traceback error stating that I have a `TYPEERROR` ... my database test works fine when I create an instance of a `video`, so I know that it is not the issue. I have investigated on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969244/typeerror-d-format-a-number-is-required-not-str), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476484/convert-unicode-data-to-int-in-python) and online the possible issue, but I haven't found anything that is appropriate.

Since creating a web framework, when attempting to create a video via the HTML form, I am now getting the following traceback:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notssdb/model/base.py", line 122, in __repr__
    return "<Video(videoname='%s', length='%d', url='%s')>" % (self.videoname, self.length, self.url)
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not unicode
```

THIS is the web code that I believe is causing the issue: 
the views setup:

```
def get_video(self):
    video_id = int(self.request.matchdict['id'])
    video = self.API.retrieve_video(video_id)
    return {'videoname': video.videoname, 'length': video.length, 'url': video.url}

@view_config(request_method='POST')
def post_video(self):
    videoname = self.request.params['videoname']
    length = self.request.params['length']
    url = self.request.params['url']
    video = self.API.create_video(videoname, length, url)
    return HTTPAccepted(location=request.route_url('/videos/{id}'))
```

the html (JINJA templates via Pyramid framework):

```
  <form method="POST" action="/videos">
      <dl>
        <dt><label for = 'videoname'> Video Name </label></dt>
        <dd>{{ forms.input('videoname') }}</dd>
        <dt><label for = 'length'> Duration </label></dt>
        <dd>{{ forms.input('int(length)') }}</dd> # < --- works 
        <dt><label for = 'url'> Video URL </label></dt>
        <dd>{{ forms.input('url') }}</dd>
        <dd><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></dd>
      </dl>
    </form>
```

Added the int() property above (see `<dd>{{ forms.input('int(length)') }}</dd> # < --- works` ), but now getting this TRACEBACK:

```
  line 93, in post_video
    length = self.request.params['length']
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-x86_64/egg/webob/multidict.py", line 342, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'length'
```

VIDEO MODEL --SQLALCHEMY:

```
class Video(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'videos'
    #code
    length = Column(Integer)
    url = Column(String(300))

    def __init__(self, videoname, length, url):
        self.videoname = videoname
        self.length = length
        self.url = url

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Video(videoname='%s', length='%s', url='%s')>" % (self.videoname, self.length, self.url)
```

Comment: Your code isn't showing the problem line, somewhere there exists `print(new_video)`. Additionally you aren't saying what you're using for templating.

Comment: I am using Pyramid and Jinja Templates. I will add the 'problem line' and the info mentioned just now. Thanks!

Comment: Actually it looks like you overwrote __str__ for a video object to be used for that custom print. You probably need to figure out how to either 1. convert the length to a number and not a unicode object, or 2. change the input type in the template.

Comment: You have to design the system so that you're using u'your_length' and the number your_length in the appropriate places. Hard to tell exactly how to do that without all the sauce.

Comment: @EugeneK added the model above and changed the input type of template above... new error shown

Answer (score 3):

**Solution for Question in Headline:**

You specify with "%d" that you expect self.length to be a number, but it is unicode at this point.

Transform self.length to a number like this float(self.length), use "%s" instead of "%d" thats pretty robust or use *format* instead of *%* ([see why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)).

```
>>> length = "23.12"
>>> "{}".format(length)
"23.12"
```

Comment: Doesn't work. See my video model above and the new error

Comment: there is no request param 'length' anymore, because you named it 'int(length)'

Comment: so change the video model to '%s' -- I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: the second error - your form does not submit a param named 'length', because you named it 'int(length)'

Comment: Right. I got rid of the ` 'int(length)' `